# How to translate this portion of C++ code to Delphi

Tags: c++, delphi

I trying to port the [RefPack compression implementation](http://download.wcnews.com/files/documents/sourcecode/shadowforce/transfer/asommers/mfcapp_src/engine/compress/RefPack.cpp) to Delphi, but I'm having trouble to understand some portions of code:

```
hashtbl = NEW int32[65536];
link    = NEW int32[131072];

hashptr = hashtbl;
for (i=0; i<65536L/16; ++i)
{
    *(hashptr+0)  = *(hashptr+1)  = *(hashptr+2)  = *(hashptr+3) =
    *(hashptr+4)  = *(hashptr+5)  = *(hashptr+6)  = *(hashptr+7) =
    *(hashptr+8)  = *(hashptr+9)  = *(hashptr+10) = *(hashptr+11) =
    *(hashptr+12) = hashptr[13] = hashptr[14] = hashptr[15] = -1L;
    hashptr += 16;
}
```

Here's my code:

```
var
hashtbl: PUInt32;
hashptr: PUInt32;

GetMem(hashtbl, 65536);
GetMem(link, 131072);

hashptr := hashtbl;

for I := 0 to (65536 div 16) - 1 do
begin
    ?!?
    hashptr := hashptr + 16;
end;
```

Question 1:
"65536L" What this "L" means?

Question 2:
I have no idea what the code inside the loop does and how to transcribe it to Delphi... Could someone enlighten me?

Ps: I'm using Delphi Community Edition.

Comment: Unrelated: I have a hard time seeing that C++ code as much faster than a `memset`. And then I think a bit more and ponder `std::vector<int32> hashtbl(65536, -1);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C++, [integer literals](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal) can include a suffix to specify the data type of the literal.  In this case, the `L` suffix is for `long`.  Delphi doesn't have such suffixes, but you can use typed constants instead.

In C++, the assignment `=` operator returns a reference to the left-hand variable that is being assigned to.  That reference can be used in subsequent expressions.  So, the expression `*(hashptr+0) = *(hashptr+1) = ... = hashptr[14] = hashptr[15] = -1L;` in C++ means that `-1` is assigned to `hashptr[15]`, then `hashptr[15]` is assigned to `hashptr[14]`, and so on until `*(hashptr+1)` is assigned to `*(hashptr+0)`.  Delphi doesn't support that, you would have to split up such an expression into individual statements.

In C++, the expressions `*(hashptr+N)` and `hashptr[N]` are *identical* in this case.  They both increment the `hashptr` pointer by `N` elements, and then dereference the result to access the element being pointed at.

So, taking everything together, the C++ code is simply looping through the `hashtbl` array, setting every element to `-1`, 16 elements per loop iteration.  A simple *literal* translation of the C++ code to Delphi would look something like this:

```pascal
{$POINTERMATH ON}

var
  hashtbl, link, hashptr: PInt32;
  i: Integer;

...

GetMem(hashtbl, SizeOf(Int32) * 65536);
GetMem(link, SizeOf(Int32) * 131072);

hashptr := hashtbl;

for i := 0 to (65536 div 16)-1 do
begin
  (hashptr+0)^ := -1;
  (hashptr+1)^ := -1;
  (hashptr+2)^ := -1;
  (hashptr+3)^ := -1;
  (hashptr+4)^ := -1;
  (hashptr+5)^ := -1;
  (hashptr+6)^ := -1;
  (hashptr+7)^ := -1;
  (hashptr+8)^ := -1;
  (hashptr+9)^ := -1;
  (hashptr+10)^ := -1;
  (hashptr+11)^ := -1;
  (hashptr+12)^ := -1;
  hashptr[13] := -1;
  hashptr[14] := -1;
  hashptr[15] := -1;
  Inc(hashptr, 16);
end;

...

FreeMem(link);
FreeMem(hashtbl);
```

Which can be greatly simplified:

```pascal
var
  hashtbl, link: array of Int32;
  i, j: Integer;

...

SetLength(hashtbl, 65536);
SetLength(link, 131072);

for i := 0 to (65536 div 16)-1 do
begin
  for j := 0 to 15 do begin
    hashtbl[(i*16)+j] := -1;
  end;
end;

...
```

Or simply:

```pascal
var
  hashtbl, link: array of Int32;
  i, j: Integer;

...

SetLength(hashtbl, 65536);
SetLength(link, 131072);

for i := 0 to 65535 do
begin
  hashtbl[i] := -1;
end;

...
```

Comment: GetMem(hashtbl, SizeOf(Int32) * 65536);
GetMem(link, SizeOf(Int32) * 131072);
I'm used to always working with PByte in Delphi and I didn't even notice my mistake when setting the memory allocation size... It saved me a lot of headache. Thanks.

Comment: @Delutto all the more reason to use dynamic arrays instead of raw memory, as my 2nd example demonstrates.

Comment: Besides, are you sure about "(hashptr+0)^ := -1;"? I'm getting error "E2015 Operator not applicable to this operand type"

Comment: @Delutto yes, I'm sure, that is why I included [`{$POINTERMATH ON}`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Pointer_Math_(Delphi)) to enable that syntax, so it can match what the C++ code is doing.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that. Just for knowledge...
I'm working with arrays, it's more "friendly".

Answer (score 1):

The `L` suffix stands for `long`. `-1L` is a `long` constant (or binary 32 ones in your example).

The second part sets every element of the `hashtbl` array to `-1`. It does it in chunks of 16 elements.

```pascal
for I := 0 to 65535 do
begin 
  hashtbl[I] := -1;
end;
```